# Internal Microphone not works Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell 7410

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, dell, alsa, microphone

I recently acquire a Dell 7410, but in a fresh install the Internal Microphone not works. It only reproduce a hiss noise. But when i use my bluetooth headset it works fine.

The lspci -nn command shows this device for audio:

**`Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]`**

And reading dmesg only can see:

```
[  +0.045497] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3254: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker

[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)

[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)

[  +0.000000] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0

[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:

[  +0.000000] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19

[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a

[  +0.000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12

[  +0.059235] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input39

[  +0.000059] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input40

[  +0.000054] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input41

[  +0.000040] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input42

[  +0.000036] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input43

[  +0.000041] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input44
```

Somebody have a clue about whats happen?